# org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher issue in web.xml

Tags: spring, resteasy, jakarta-migration, servlet-listeners

In our application we have web.xml where
previously java 8 and resteasy 4.7.7.Final was used

Now javax -> jakarta is being done and spring version used is 5.3.30

Intellij shows this error in web.xml org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Servlet' but compilation and build is done but deployment in wildfly 27.0.1 and jboss 19 is causing deployment failure Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010012: Listener class class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener must implement at least one listener interface

please let me know what changes can be made to bring up the deployment

suggest ways to resolve

Comment: <servlet>
<servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>
jakarta.ws.rs.Application
</param-name>
<param-value>
XYZApplication
</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet> is defined.

Comment: Spring 5 is not Jakartified. Spring 6 is the first Jakartified version. And please note that WildFly by default already provides RESTEasy out the box.

Comment: @BalusC the problem is that we are moving to java 11 and jakarta as our initial steps of migration and the wildfly that we are using is 27.0.1. If I upgrade to spring 6 it's not compatible with java 11. So suggest me an workaround for the same.

Comment: Just move further to Java 17. No big deal as compared to Java 11. Java 8 -> 9 is the biggest effort. But as you're already on 11, then 17 should be practically effortless.

Comment: It's kind off legacy code that we are dealing with. We have kept the option of movement to java 17 to last. Thanks

Comment: You could try the [`deployment-transformer-feature-pack`](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/deployment-transformer-feature-pack) which will convert the byte code.